# How to use callBack() Hooks with FlatList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to improve the performance on my app, so I use FC to render items,

but it's not work fine with me!

when i scroll to down i ++page

and in useEffect() I send a request to get the new data based on the page its work and render item well in UI! "load More feature".

But when I log the "songs" whole array before I click on the item I just get the first two pages! and sometimes I get an empty array.

So what's the wrong in my code here?

```
const LastSongs = (props) => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [last_page, setLast_page] = React.useState(1);

  const {saveSongs, isPlaying, isPauseTrigger} = props;

  const _renderItems = useCallback(
    // the same reference with each rerender
    ({item, index}) => (
      <TouchableNativeFeed
        key={item.id}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log('onPress', songs);
          saveSongs(songs, index);
          isPlaying(true);
          isPauseTrigger(!isPauseTrigger);
        }}
        background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('white')}
        delayPressIn={0}
        useForeground>
        <Card
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#121212',
            flex: 1,
          }}>
          <FastImage
            source={{uri: item.img}}
            resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            style={styles.cardImg}
          />
          <Body style={{...styles.cardItem, width: '100%'}}>
            <View style={styles.radioCardName}>
              <Text style={styles.text} numberOfLines={1}>
                {item.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </Body>
        </Card>
      </TouchableNativeFeed>
    ),
    [saveSongs, isPlaying, isPauseTrigger],
  );

  const renderFooter = useCallback(
    // the same reference with each rerender
    () => {
      return loading ? (
        <View style={styles.loader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      ) : null;
    },
    [loading],
  );

  const handleLoadMore = useCallback(
    // the same reference with each rerender
    () => {
      if (page <= last_page - 1) {
        setPage(page + 1);
      }
    },
    [page, last_page],
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let isCancelled = false;
    setLoading(true);

    const getData = async () => {
      let response = await API.get(`/tracks?page=${page}`);
      let lastPage = response.data.data.items.last_page;
      setLast_page(lastPage);
      let {
        data: {
          data: {
            items: {data},
          },
        },
      } = response;
      let All_Songs = [];
      data.map((track) =>
        All_Songs.push({
          id: track.id,
          name: track.name,
          url: URL + track.sounds,
          img: URL + track.avatar,
        }),
      );
      setSongs(songs.concat(All_Songs));
      setLoading(false);
    };
    getData();
    console.log('songs', songs);
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <Header
        style={styles.darkHeader}
        androidStatusBarColor="#121212"
        iosBarStyle="light-content">
        <Left>
          <Button transparent onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Icon name="ios-arrow-forward" style={styles.colorWhite} />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title style={styles.headerText}>last songs</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right></Right>
      </Header>
      <FlatList
        data={songs}
        keyExtractor={_keyExtractor} // the same reference with each rerender
        initialNumToRender={10}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle} // the same reference with each rerender
        columnWrapperStyle={styles.columnWrapperStyle} // the same reference with each rerender
        numColumns={2}
        ListEmptyComponent={_renderListEmptyComponent} // the same reference with each rerender
        renderItem={_renderItems}
        onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={100}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={1} // Reduce number in each render batch
        maxToRenderPerBatch={100} // Increase time between renders
        windowSize={7}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

const _keyExtractor = (song) => song.id;

const _renderListEmptyComponent = () => <EmptyList />;

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    isPlaying: (_isPlaying) => {
      dispatch(isPlayingAction(_isPlaying));
    },

    isPauseTrigger: (_isPause) => {
      dispatch(isPauseAction(_isPause));
    },

    saveSongs: (songs, index) => {
      dispatch(saveSongsPlayer(songs, index));
    },
  };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LastSongs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the dependency array on _renderItems to include songs. Change it to:
`[saveSongs, isPlaying, isPauseTrigger, songs]`. That way the closure on the callBack will always include the latest songs.

I'd highly recommend using the react-hooks eslint options. They will significantly help you make sure you aren't missing things in your dependency arrays.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks

If there was only an issue with that after you added songs to the dependency array of the list, then you can try:

```
const songsRef = useRef(songs);
useEffect(() => {
  songsRef.current = songs;
}, [songs]);
```

And then use songsRef.current instead of songs in the _renderItems function

Update from chat:

Okay, fixed the infinite loop: [expo snack](http://snack.expo.io/U2GSXh7wH)

The reason why there was an infinite loop was because you had songs in the useEffect's dependency array. Which meant that everytime the useEffect appended to the songs array, the useEffect would re-trigger.

I fixed it by removing songs from the array and then using the useState's callback method to setting state: setSongs(songs=>songs.concat(all_songs));

Comment: I got this warning in debugger `VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. ` 
and I just log the songs array inside useEffect() it's log too many time, I will check react-hooks eslint now

Comment: I add react-hooks eslint plugin but i don't see any warning or error :\

Comment: Try changing setSongs in the useEffect to `setSongs((songs)=>songs.concat(All_Songs));`
 Otherwise I don't know if I'll be able to help without a working code to test changes on.

Comment: sadly not work well, and when I put console.log("rerender") inside render I can see log for the first time it's In infinity rerender!.

Comment: If I recreate it in a class-based component, how can I prevent the re-rendering? Especially in this case "scroll to load more item" should I use componentDidUpdate or shouldUpdate?

Comment: Probably not. I think there's likely something beyond what I'm seeing here that leads to the infinite re-rendering issue.

Comment: Are you check it?

Comment: By it's in infinite re-render, do you mean that the loading spinner spins forever? Or that  you are seing that 'rerender' message being created infinitely?

Comment: yeah 'rerender' message created infinitely, check thee log you will see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211101/discussion-between-zachary-haber-and-oliver-d).